# Total population size variance knowing the resulted sample count with a fixed/known sampling probability

Tags: binomial-distribution, variance

*I will give a hypothetical example to explain my question.*

Assume we have **N** people (**N** unknown). These people are standing in a line to pass through a gate one by one. The gatekeeper will decide to send each person passing by to be questioned with a known fixed probability **p** (*i.e., he will generate a uniform random number, $u$, and if $u<$**p** he will send that person for questioning*).

At the end of this process, you will come in to the room where all selected people are gathered. You count how many they are. They are **M** of them.

In this situation the total number of people **N** is unknown.

It's intuitive that an unbiased estimate of the total number of people **N** is: $\hat{N}=\frac{M}{p}$.

> My question is what is the $Var(\hat{N})$ ?

Comment: Thanks. corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

You're just dividing by the constant $p$, so the variance is $\frac1{p^2}$ times the variance of $M$:

$$
\operatorname{Var}\hat N=\frac1{p^2}\operatorname{Var}M=\frac{np(1-p)}{p^2}=\frac{n(1-p)}p\;.
$$

I took the liberty of adjusting the capitalization to the usual conventions. I'm not sure what you mean when you say that $n$ is a random variable; as far as I can tell it's a fixed unknown parameter.

Comment: Thanks. I will correct my mention of N being random variable. I came up with the same equation, but simulation studies for the 95% confidence interval shows a higher coverage percentage. Could it be the distribution is non-normal ?

Comment: @user1780424: Yes, the distribution is binomial; for small $np$ the difference can be significant.

Comment: simulation study was with super large np. Would you mind showing how can we obtain the $\hat{N} = M/p$ using maximum likelihood estimator?

I was thinking of getting the fisher information and maybe the 'bias-correction' that is required for correcting second-order bias of the maximum likelihood estimator can then help in coverage percentages.

Comment: @user1780424: You can't get $\hat N$ as the maximum likelihood estimator, since $\hat N$ yields non-integer values, whereas the actual values of $N$ that you can calculate likelihoods for are integers. Even if you generalized the binomial distribution to non-integer $n$, the maximum likelihood wouldn't be at $n/p$. For instance, if you observe $M=1$ for $p=0.5$, your estimate would be $\hat n=2$, but the likelihood $n\cdot0.5^n$ is $0.5$ for both $n=1$ and $n=2$ and its maximum for non-integer $n$ is $1/(\mathrm e\ln2)\approx0.53$ at $n=1/\log2\approx1.44$.

Comment: @user1780424: If your $np$ is small enough to cause problems with deviations from normality, perhaps you should consider whether a Bayesian approach might be more appropriate.